# Docker Swarm free to use? can be used in production for free?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am a beginner so asking this silly question. Is docker swarm free to use for building cluster of docker containers? i heard it is $15/hr ? We can use swarm in production without paying anything? any limitations on it?

Also can i run specific docker containers on dedicated hosts and run some selected containers on other hosts?

Comment: Swarm is just a a set of features in the free, totally open source, docker engine. (aka Docker CE at store.docker.com). Docker EE, the paid version of docker, add's advanced security, ops, and GUI features on top of Swarm, but many use Swarm (including myself) for free in production.

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can use docker swarm in production without paying anything.

You have to pay to use the following:

- Docker Trusted Registry - DTR
- Universal Control Pane - UCP

But if you want to use docker's trusted registry (DTR) and UCP, you will have to pay a license. The license is based on number of nodes you have installed the docker daemon. I talk about these from my personal work and experience in using docker.

Comment: is it must obligatory to use UCP or DTR? without them also we can use swarm?

Comment: @Farhan You don't need UCP or DTR. You will probably need to look into an alternate registry for storing images.

Comment: Links to the services: [DTR](https://docs.docker.com/ee/dtr/) [UCP](https://docs.docker.com/ee/ucp/)